# Can't color text with \textoverline

Tags: color, text-manipulation

When I add `\textcolor` to `\textoverline`, I get:

`Error: Undefined control sequence.`

I need to use `color` and `textoverline` for the same text. It is not working with me. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox\TBox
\def\textoverline#1{\savebox\TBox{#1}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{#1}\rule[1.1\ht\TBox]{\wd\TBox}{0.4pt}}
\begin{document}

\textcolor{red} {\textoverline{foo}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In preamble you should add package `color` or `xcolor`

Comment: BTW,  your definition does not allow line breaks. It is better use    `\usepackage{umoline}` ... `\Overline{foo}`, imho.

Comment: The undefined-control-sequence error message occurs at `\textcolor`, not at `\textoverline`. As @Zarko has noted, load a package such as `xcolor`.